# What is the difference between -m conntrack --ctstate and -m state --state

Tags: iptables

I'm reading [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) howto, and there's something like this:

> We can allow established sessions to receive traffic:
>
> ```
> $ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
> ```
>
> The above rule has no spaces either side of the comma in ESTABLISHED,RELATED
>
> If the line above doesn't work, you may be on a castrated VPS whose
>   provider has not made available the extension, in which case an
>   inferior version can be used as last resort:
>
> ```
> $ sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
> ```

Is there a significant difference in working between `-m conntrack --ctstate` and `-m state --state`? They say that one may not work, but they don't say why. Why should I prefer one over the other?

Comment: Possible dup of http://serverfault.com/questions/358996/iptables-whats-the-difference-between-m-state-and-m-conntrack

Comment: I see it, should I remove this question?

Comment: After having it, is there some part of this question that remains unanswered?  If so, I suggest refocusing this question on that part.

Comment: @John1024 - duplicates are only within a single SE site. It's perfectly fine to post similar questions on multiple SE sites so long as the Q's are within the rules governing a particular SE site!

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov - your question, though similar to other Q's on other SE sites is perfectly fine here!

Comment: I'll remember that. :)

Comment: Note that the `-m state` version is deprecated in favor of `-m conntrack`.

Comment: @Totor - if you see my "data point #4" in my answer `state` is actually an alias to `conntrack`. So it doesn't matter. I suppose at some point in the future they may remove `state` altogether but for the time being it doesn't matter if you use it.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I don't claim to be an expert with `iptables` rules but the first command is making use of the connection tracking extension (`conntrack`) while the second is making use of the `state` extension.

#### Data point #1

According to [this document](http://inai.de/documents/Perfect_Ruleset.pdf) the `conntrack` extension superseded `state`.

```
 Obsolete extensions:
  • -m state: replaced by -m conntrack
```

#### Data point #2

Even so I found this SF Q&A titled: [Firewall questions about state and policy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/190978/firewall-questions-about-state-and-policy) where the OP claimed to have asked this question on IRC in #iptables@freenode. After discussing it there he came to the conclusion that:

> Technically the conntrack match supersedes - and so obsoletes - the state match. But practically the state match is not obsoleted in any way.

#### Data point #3

Lastly I found this SF Q&A titled: [Iptables, what's the difference between -m state and -m conntrack?](https://serverfault.com/questions/358996/iptables-whats-the-difference-between-m-state-and-m-conntrack). The answer from this question is probably the best evidence and advice on how to view the usage of `conntrack` and `state`.

*excerpt*

> Both use same kernel internals underneath (connection tracking
>   subsystem).
>
> Header of xt_conntrack.c:
>
> ```
> xt_conntrack - Netfilter module to match connection tracking
> information. (Superset of Rusty's minimalistic state match.)
> ```
>
> So I would say -- state module is simpler (and maybe less error
>   prone). It's also longer in kernel. Conntrack on the other side has
>   more options and features <sub>[1]</sub>.
>
> My call is to use conntrack if you need it's features, otherwise stick
>   with state module.
>
> - [Similar question on netfilter
>     maillist.](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg46827.html)
>
> **[1]** Quite useful like `"-m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j MASQUERADE"`
>   routing/DNAT fixup ;-)

#### Data point #4

I found this thread from the netfilter@vger.kernel.org netfilte/iptables discussions, titled: [state match is obsolete 1.4.17](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.firewalls.netfilter.general/45564), which pretty much says that `state` is just an alias to `conntrack` so it doesn't really matter which you use, in both circumstances you're using `conntrack`.

*excerpt*

> > > Actually, I have to agree. Why don't we keep "state" as an alias and 
> > >       accept the old syntax in "conntrack"?
> >
> > state is currently aliased and translated to conntrack in iptables
> >     if the kernel has it. No scripts are broken.
> >
> > If the aliasing is done in userspace, the kernel part can be removed -
> >     someday maybe.
>
> The aliasing is already done in userspace. One types in "state" and
>   it's  converted into "conntrack" and that is then sent to the kernel.
>   (So as far  as I see if the ipt_state, etc module aliases were added
>   to the conntrack  module, even the state kernel module could be
>   removed.)

#### References

- [Firewall questions about state and policy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/190978/firewall-questions-about-state-and-policy)
- [iptables: differences using conntrack or state module](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1028574)

Answer (score 9):

I am not an netfilter expert, but i looked into the iptables-extension man-page and suprise, there it is

```
The "state" extension is a subset of the "conntrack" module.
```

So state is a part of conntrack and just a simpler version of it if you really just need --state and non of the more fancy features of conntrack