# set connection limit via iptables

Tags: iptables

I want to limit the IP traffic of an application (AceStream Player).
The problem is that I get disconnected, if too many IP connections are established.

Does anyone know, how to use iptables to limit the connections to e.g. 10/second?

Inspirated by the answer below, I tried:

```
$iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8621 -m limit --limit 10/s -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8621 -j DROP
```

This seems to limit the connections, but somehow to a lower limit like 2-3/sec. Do the upper rules limit the connections or packets to 10/sec?

Is it also possible to delay the connections by using QUEUE instead of DROP?

Comment: input or output connections?

Comment: I used iptraf to look at the TCP connections.. the source host seems to be my IP, thus I would guess output.. does it work for both?

Comment: Not a problem guys, when I looked at these 2 Q's they looked like dups to me, reopening!

Comment: If you want to slow down and effectively queue packets, then look at [tc](http://www.iplocation.net/tools/traffic-control.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit the rate at which new connections are established. If you simply use `-m limit` you would be [limiting the packet rate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163657/set-packet-rate-limit-via-iptables), regardless of whether it's a new connection packet or a data packet for an existing connection.

According to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108169/what-is-the-difference-between-m-conntrack-ctstate-and-m-state-state) you can use `-m state` for that. The whole iptables ruleset would be:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 10/s -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
```

You may prefer to fine tune this rules a little, the way they are they match anything coming out.

For instance, to only limit tcp connections this way, and leave anything else through:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 10/s -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT
```

Note that I only changed the last rule, everything else will be accepted by default or fall down to your other rules.

To go further you should really learn iptables. @sailor already pointed you to a great book on the subject. There are [plenty](https://serverfault.com/questions/158772/can-you-recommend-a-good-intro-to-iptables) of [good resources online](http://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/) as well. Once you get the concepts handled by iptables (chains, tables, rules and policies) you'll find `man 8 iptables` has all the answers.

Using a frontend to iptables is also a good option if you don't have the time to get deep into iptables. I use [shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) for most firewalls I manage.

Comment: thx! how could I fine tune the rules in order to limit only TCP connections?

Comment: I added teh codez. Regarding the somewhat lower limit you see, read up on burst or `--limit-burst`.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done with the `--limit` option.

For example, `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 10/s -j ACCEPT` should be a good place to get started.

I also recommend looking at Linux iptables pocket reference by Gregor Purdy (ISBN: 0-596-00569-5). I use it any time I have a question with iptables.

Comment: thanks for the reference, but I still can't find a useful rule... I assume I need also a REJECT rule for iptables?